# What does it mean to show that the pullback of two morphisms is "unique to equivalence"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, terminology, definition

> Prove: If the pullback of two morphisms $p : E \rightarrow E$ and $q : D \rightarrow D$ exists, then it is unique to equivalence.

What does it mean to show that the pullback $(Z, r, s)$ is unique to equivalence?

Comment: I believe it should be "up to," if the phrasing is what is confusing you.

Comment: I understand what "up to" means, but what does it mean by "up to equivalence"?  What does it mean to show that a pullback -- which is an ordered triple -- is unique to equivalence?

Comment: Up to isomorphism (I am not too familiar with category theory, but that's the usual meaning of the phrase, and [Wikipedia seems to agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)#Universal_property)).

Comment: For the pullback of two morphisms $p$ and $q$ to make sense, $p$ and $q$ should have the same codomain. Your statement, as such, is ill-typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if $(\mathbb Z',r',s')$ also is a pullback, then there is a unique isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z'$ such that the completed diagram is commutative.